# grok pattern failure and unable to convert to float using logstash

Tags: type-conversion, logstash, logstash-grok

Trouble converting numbers using grok pattern - text doesn't get converted to float.  I have read several articles and now hitting a wall.    AIRCRAFTLAT is a field queried from DB. Getting _grokparsefailure now. also the field remains text and not a float

```
filter {    
    grok {
        match => { "AIRCRAFTLAT" => "%{NUMBER:alat:float}" }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you put a practical example and maybe print AIRCRAFTLAT so we can ensure which value is reported?

Comment: I got it - its the caps - should have been "aircraftlat" no caps for my data

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Carlo and others - I got it - its the caps - should have been "aircraftlat" no caps for my data - its one of those days... :)